# what is good practice for api call to return get/delete request?

Tags: rest, api, http, playframework

I have api call to get children of a person and api to delete child of person:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/api/person/1/children

DELETE http://localhost:9000/api/person/1/child/2
```

currently when someone call get children by person id I return 200 if the call succeed and a list of the children id's if there are children and if no children so empty list. and 500 if anything else.

and when you want to delete a person child by their ids i return 200 if the call succeed (also case there is no person and children ids combination in my db table), and 500 if anything else.

my question is, should I give more descriptive error incase there is no relation between those..? the db call only return 1/0 in case of deletion so to do something like this it means i need to perform another db call to check it, or tell the user if its 0 so nothing happened (and this incase db call did not find a record)...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error is just a generic server error response, I would be inclined to use a 404 when trying to call a get or delete as this indicates that the resource was not found, this can be either because there was an issue with what was sent to the API (such as junk data) or because the resource actually doesn't exist.

Should you want to do an extra db call is entirely up to you, often premature optimizations don't provide much in the way of benefits. However if you were to be facing 1000 calls a second it would probably be better to just let it fail and handle that gracefully than to check before.

> 10.4.5 404 Not Found
>
> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html